# Get translation for two keys in ng2-translate with pipe

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ng2-translate

I have this situation where I interpolate error variable which contains dynamic values.

```
{{ errorMsg | translate }}
```

I feed errorMsg a key everytime there is an error of any kind. Like

```
this.errorMsg = "error.loading.results"
this.errorMsg = "server.error"
```

those are my keys which are translated by the pipe and it works well.

But I want to translate two keys at the same time. How do I do that?
Something like:

```
{{ ['error.loading.result', 'server.error'] | translate }}
```

which should result in

```
"Error loading result. Server Error"
```

where the key value pair in en-US.json is:

```
"error.loading.result": "Error loading result.",
"server.error": "Server Error"
```

Is this doable?